# Problems reading PointCloud2 message

Tags: sensor-msgs, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I'm trying to find an object by color and then get the distance to it.
However I'm having trouble reading the PointCloud2 message.

I can see through RVIZ that the topic is sending the right cloud, however when I try to read it through my code I am having some issues:

- The x,y,z are sometimes negative
- The rgb values are almost zero (6.82247660989e-39 for example).

My code for getting the RGB values of the cloud:

```
generator = pc2.read_points(cloud, field_names = ['rgb'], skip_nans = True)

matrix = np.empty(shape = (cloud.height, cloud.width), dtype=float)
for i, element in enumerate(generator):
    print element[0] // for debugging reasons, prints a near-zero float
    np.put(matrix, [[i / cloud.width, i % cloud.width]], [element[0]])
```

Note that the variable cloud is the PointCloud2 message recieved from the topic, and pc2 is the namespace PointCloud2.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get a matrix to use with OpenCV2?

I'm using ROS Indigo, running through Gazebo.
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278009/problems-reading-pointcloud2-message/) by [Null Terminator](https://answers.ros.org/users/32985/null-terminator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to solve the bgr issue thanks to the lovely topic here:
[link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/208834/read-colours-from-a-pointcloud2-python/)

For future readers:
All 3 colors are merged in a same float (binary-wise) and they require some bitwise operations to read.
My code is as follows:

```
def on_new_img(msg):
    print 'got something!!'

    bgr = cloud2bgr(msg)

    cv2.imshow("img", bgr)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    
def bgr_gen(sequence):
    for element in sequence:
        #convert to int so bitwise operations become enabled
        s = struct.pack('>f' ,element[0])
        i = struct.unpack('>l',s)[0]

        pack = ctypes.c_uint32(i).value
        r = (pack & 0x00FF0000)>> 16
        g = (pack & 0x0000FF00)>> 8
        b = (pack & 0x000000FF)

        yield (float(b) /255, float(g) / 255, float(r) / 255)

def cloud2bgr(cloud):
    generator = pc2.read_points(cloud, field_names = ['rgb'], skip_nans = True)
    bgr_generator = bgr_gen(generator)

    matrix = np.empty(shape = (cloud.height, cloud.width, 3), dtype=float)

    for row in range(cloud.height):
        for col in range(cloud.width):
            matrix[row][col] = bgr_generator.next()

    return matrix
```

---

Originally posted by [Null Terminator](https://answers.ros.org/users/32985/null-terminator/) with karma: 16 on 2017-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0